# Aero Shake - only one monitor?

Tags: windows-7, aero, multiple-monitors

Is there anyway to make aero shake only minimise windows on the active monitor in a dual monitor setup?

Comment: Oh geez, I wish!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows detects multi-monitor set-ups as "1 background", this is most easily visible when taking a screenshot, it caps everything, the OS "knows" that there are multiple monitors connected, but it isn't able to seperate them for commands like that... yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Maybe by writing a program which would detect that windows are minimized, and restore those on the left side... but it's highly unlikely that something like that already exists.